# How to open system files in html?

Tags: html

When button in some web application clicked it opens system file. My project also needs such a thing to choose images from computer. So how can I do it?

Comment: You can open a file dialog with `<input type="file">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for `<input name="myFile" type="file">` no javascript is needed for it.

```html
<input name="myFile" type="file">
```

[More information about it can be found here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file)

Answer (score 0):

`<input name="mFile" type="file">`
 this will open wizard and you will choose file from it!
if you want drag and drop functionality then 
you can also used dropzone.js (http://www.dropzonejs.com/)!